# What would a regex for common file name extensions for images look like?

Tags: php, regex, file-upload, mime, mime-types

I am starting on making so images turns out as small thumbnails.

But I need a regular expression to check if it contains `*.jpg, *.jpeg, .*png, *.gif`

How can that be made?

Comment: Karem, some important questions you need to answer to get the correct solution... Why do you think you need this regular expression? ~~ What language or software are you using it with? ~~ If I renamed a non-image file to fake.jpg what would your thumbnail converter do?

Comment: @Peter boughton, im working with PHP, im trying to do so it shows a little snippet of the image by the url you enter in. is this bad?

Comment: Just because something has an extension of .jpg (or whatever), doesn't mean it actually is a jpeg - especially so if you are accepting content over the web. If you're only checking extension, a malicious user could potentially feed you a fake jpeg that crashes the server (or worse). I can't give a specific PHP example, but basically for a jpeg you check that the first four bytes are "FFD8" and the last four bytes are "FFD9" and then you've probably got a valid image - other examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files)

Comment: The stuff you just describe, does this also needs to be checked in my profileimage upload (not related to this question), right now my image upload only checks for extension and proceed if its one of the common images.. Thanks for the link, and can i check without saving the image?

Comment: I'll ask a new question about this. Thank you for expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)\b
```

will match if the tested string *contains* `.jpeg`, `.png` or one of the other alternatives.

```
\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$
```

will match if the tested string *ends in* `.jpeg`, `.png` etc.

Comment: What are the `(?:)` and `\b` for?

Comment: @Brad `?:` non-capturing group (since we're not using the extension for anything), `\b` boundary (since we don't want to match `look at my .gifs`)

Comment: Depending on regex engine, could also consider a lookbehind like `(?<=\S)` or `(?<=[\w-])` to ensure you've not got stuff like "I uploaded the .jpg" or "I searched for *.jpg" and so on.

Comment: @Peter, but you're assuming that the filename is not *actually* `I uploaded the .jpg`, which it technically could be. The OP needs to give more context.

Comment: Good point. Re-reading the question, I'm actually thinking the OP is trying to do mime-type checking based on extension (rather than checking the first 4/8 bytes of the file).

Answer (score 2):

To match the entire filename of images

```
(^|\s+).+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|tiff)(\s+|$)
```

***NOTE:** the `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, so if you are pulling the names out of some larger text, remove those characters. By adding the option of string terminator (`^` or `$`) of `space`, it makes the filename have to appear at the beginning/end of the string *or* to be flanked by spaces. Since spaces are allow in filenames, this may/may not work for the OP, however, we don't have much information on the context in which he plans to use the expression.

---

To prevent a filename that is just a dot:

```
^.?[^\.]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|tiff)$
```

Comment: Why the `^.+`? `\.(jpe?g|png|gif|tiff)$` is identical.

Comment: The leading dot plus makes sure you don’t match files with *only* an extension, that is, which begin with a dot, like `name=".jpg"`. However, `..jpg` still works.

Comment: This will only match if the extension is at the end of the string - @Karem asked for a regex that finds it *anywhere* in the string ("contains"). Which might not be what he meant, but who knows?

Comment: @tchrist Sorry, you're right. `^.*` would have been identical, not `^.+`. Oops.

Comment: `..jpg` is a valid filename, so there's no reason to check against it, but I added the option for the OP.

Comment: @Tim, the OP didn't really give much detail about *how* he's going to use this expression.

Comment: @Brad: Exactly, and it's reasonable to assume that a match should always be at the end. But I wanted to point out this assumption and that it at least should be mentioned what this regex really does. If you do remove the `$`, you should replace it with a `\b`, probably. Although it's just another assumption that the OP doesn't want `.tiffany` to match :)

Comment: Don't escape `.` inside character classes. Also you're preventing x.y.png with that last example.

Comment: Corrected based on the last two comments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a regular expression for that...

But if you really want a regex, you can use

```
(jpeg|png|gif|jpg)$
```

It should make it.

I recommand you to use substr, it will run faster.

**EDIT**
Add a period to check for extension, not just end of name (or longer extension), e.g. `myjpg` or `otherfile.xgif`:

```
\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
```

Comment: Don’t micro-optimize. A `substr` won’t run faster if enough alternatives compile into a fast trie data structure, which occurs with modern perls.

Comment: This does not do what the OP asked for.